# Error while compiling using Dev-C++

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile the following code using Dev-C++ on a WinXP machine:

```
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow
)
{
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error message;

> C:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-git\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crt0_c.c   undefined
>   reference to `WinMain@16'

I've search for the error message but I don't understand what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm a real noob at c++ so sorry if it seems obvious for you guys.

Comment: It seems your IDE does not find an entry point to your program.

Comment: Can't you code for standard C++11 and have your `int main(int argc, char**argv)` function....

Comment: PS: you also need to call [TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Don't use Dev-C++, it is old and should be abandoned.

Comment: @MKII I'm using orwelldevcpp, is it outdated? http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Comment: @DevRandom My bad, didn't know the project was superseded/revived. Never mind, carry on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try replacing _tWinMain with WinMain.

Comment: the _tWinMain is a define so that WinMain will work when compiling with Ansi or Unicode, optionally you could include <tchar.h> if your compiler has that.

Comment: It worked! The compilation ran without any errors! @MarkJansen Now when it compiled without any error, I don't need to include <tchar.h> , right?